# How to implement reset button in Scenekit and UIView?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, scenekit, 3d-modelling

Looking for some help from anyone who knows how the heck all this stuff works. I can't find any concrete way of doing this seemingly common task online, so I'm posting it. Here's the lowdown:

First up is the SwiftUI ModelViewer. This is a simple view that creates a CustomSceneView to show the 3D model.  There's a reset button that is supposed to reset the model and/or camera to its original position.  You know, like anytime you mess with 3D stuff and want to go back to the beginning because something weird happened.  Seems like a simple enough task, but I've been struggling.  A user can do all the classic movement stuff, including zooming in/out and rotating the model into any direction/orientation.

```
struct ModelViewer: View {
    @State var scene: SCNScene?
    @State private var camera: Camera?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomSceneView(
                scene: self.$scene,
                camera: self.$camera
            )

            Button("Reset") {
                self.camera = .default
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.25))
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .foregroundColor(.prismBlack)
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's the code that's actually handling all this functionality:

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct Camera {
    static let `default` = Camera(
        position: SCNVector3(x: 0.805120, y: 0.057330, z: 1.4),
        rotation: SCNVector4(0, 0, 0, 0),
        orientation: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1.0)
    )

    let position: SCNVector3
    let rotation: SCNVector4
    let orientation: SCNVector4

    init(position: SCNVector3, rotation: SCNVector4, orientation: SCNVector4) {
        self.position = position
        self.rotation = rotation
        self.orientation = orientation
    }

    init(from node: SCNNode) {
        self.init(position: node.position, rotation: node.rotation, orientation: node.orientation)
    }
}

struct CustomSceneView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias Context = UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>
    typealias UIViewType = SCNView

    @Binding var scene: SCNScene?
    @Binding var camera: Camera?

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        return context.coordinator.view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.set(camera: self.camera)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
        private let parent: CustomSceneView
        private let camera = SCNCamera()
        private let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        private let contentNode = SCNNode()
        private let scene = SCNScene()

        let view = SCNView()

        init(_ parent: CustomSceneView) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()

            self.view.delegate = self
            self.view.pointOfView = self.cameraNode
            self.view.allowsCameraControl = true
            self.view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
            self.view.scene = self.scene

            self.camera.name = "Camera"
            self.camera.focalLength = 50
            self.camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true

            self.cameraNode.name = "CameraNode"
            self.cameraNode.camera = self.camera
            self.cameraNode.position = parent.camera?.position ?? Camera.default.position
            self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.cameraNode)

            self.contentNode.name = "ContentNode"
            self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.contentNode)

            guard let scene = parent.scene else { return }
            self.addChildNodes(from: scene)
        }

        private func addChildNodes(from scene: SCNScene) {
            scene.rootNode.childNodes.forEach({ node in
                node.name = "Model"
                node.scale = SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0)
                node.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.8, y: -0.75, z: -0.25)
                node.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: .pi / 2)
                self.contentNode.addChildNode(node)
            })
        }

        func set(camera: Camera?) {
            guard let camera else { return }
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1
            self.view.pointOfView?.position = camera.position
            self.view.pointOfView?.rotation = camera.rotation
            self.view.pointOfView?.orientation = camera.orientation
            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }

        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
            self.parent.camera = nil
        }

        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {

        }

        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

        }
    }
}
```

Notably, I'm doing this all very granularly because the model I have to use is very fickle.  Can't change the model though, so the camera and node positioning is my only option.  Now, the code here mostly works, you can click the button and the model will usually reset.  However, if the model is in motion when you click the button, the reset will trigger but the ultimate position will be in some random state.  Also, if a user zooms in or out, then the model will reset the positioning, but not the zoom.  So, if anyone has some tips or tricks on how to make this a true reset of the model regardless of zoom, movement, etc., they would be greatly appreciated!!

Edit: By adding `self.view.pointOfView?.camera?.fieldOfView = camera.fieldOfView` into the `set` method (where fieldOfView has a default value set in the default camera), I can get the zoom to reset correctly.  However, if the model is in motion when the reset button is pressed, it still doesn't reset properly.

Answer (score 1):

By using `SCNAction` and creating a custom action, I was able to get this to work.  Although it doesn't have any animation (model just jumps right back to the original position), it at least resets properly even while in motion.  If anyone has any idea on how to make the model transition smoothly back to the position, I am still open to suggestions.

```
func set(camera: Camera?) {
    guard let camera else { return }
    
    let action = SCNAction.customAction(duration: 1, action: { _, _ in
        self.view.pointOfView?.position = camera.position
        self.view.pointOfView?.rotation = camera.rotation    
        self.view.pointOfView?.orientation = camera.orientation
        self.view.pointOfView?.camera?.fieldOfView = camera.fieldOfView
            })
    self.view.scene?.rootNode.runAction(action)
}
```